# WooCommerce: Get URL of paged shop archive

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, canonical-link, yoast

I need the link to the paged shop archive URL to add it as `rel=canonical`.
As default WooCommerce seems to use always the URL of the "All products" page.

For example: The all product archive page has the following URL:

```
https://example.com/shop/
```

If I go to page 2, the URL is still the one from above.
But the correct version would be:

```
https://example.com/shop/page/2/
```

I try to rewrite the `rel=canonical` tag with Yoast and want to display the current URL with `/page/`.
So I tried this:

```
$canonical = home_url( $wp->request );
```

And this:

```
$canonical = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
```

Unfortunately without success. It always shows only the URL of homepage (`https://example.com`)
Is there any way to get the number of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found a solution for that.
It seems that `$wp->request` doesn't work on the WooCommerce shop archive.

Here's a solution that works. But it has some hard coded URL parts in it:

```
$canonical = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ).'page/'.get_query_var('paged').'/';
```

I wonder if there is a better solution without adding `/page/` to the URL.

Comment: PHP Deprecated:  woocommerce_get_page_id is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 3.0! Use wc_get_page_id instead.

Comment: Use  wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) instead, more succinct.